# Индекс на свойства навигации в Ef Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

при конфигурации маппинга моделей через Fluent API я могу написать так

```
builder.HasIndex(x => x.Name).IsUnique();
```

Таким образом я создам для нужного свойства сущности уникальный индекс.
Если я хочу создать индекс на несколько свойств я могу написать так

```
builder.HasIndex(x => new { x.Name, x.LastName }).IsUnique();
```

Но вот если я хочу создать индекс на свойство навигации, я не знаю как правильно поступить

```
builder.HasIndex(x => x.Person).IsUnique();
```

уже не работает. При создании миграции EF ругается на то, что не знает как создать индекс на этот тип.

Я всегда при этом указывал в качестве индекса его строковое представление. Я знаю, что Person по умолчанию встанет в таблицу под именем PersonId.

Но это не очень удобно, потому что завтра конвенция именования может поменяться и все индексы придется переписывать. Или же конкретный столбец явно переименуется.

Или же я создавал явно в сущности свойство PersonId рядом с Person. Но это мне не очень нравится (причины объяснять сейчас не буду).

В общем я подумал, если EF знает, какой столбец соответствует свойству навигации x.Person, почему бы мне не спросить его, какое имя столбца соответствует данному свойству. Но я не знаю как. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: x => x.PersonId? Чем не нравится такой вариант? Поменяется нейминг - при миграции всё само обновится (если переименовывать не руками, а через ПКМ - Переименовать).

Comment: @OwDafuq, Не всегда такое переименование срабатывает. Хоть через рефакторинг это делать хоть как. Нигде в миграциях или же в снапшоте информация переименования не хранится. Если я переименую 2 текстовых свойства, EF  удалит и пересоздаст столбцы. Конечно, я могу руками подправить миграцию. Но дело даже не в этом. я не очень хочу видеть в моделях идентификаторы для свойств навигации. По мне так это засорение. Но это долгий разговор :)

Comment: Штош... `x => x.Person.Id` пробовали? Не уверен, что прокатит, но кто знает

Comment: @OwDafuq пробовал. Говорит что для индекса надо указывать простые доступы к свойствам (x.Name, x.Address и тд)

Comment: Придется делать через x.PersonId, хоть это и противоречит мои представлениям прекрасного )) Но вдруг кто все же знает более изящный способ )

Comment: Вообще, если у вас там связь, то он должен сам, вроде бы, поставить индекс на эту колонку, по крайней мере у меня в проекте сейчас так, сначала забыл индекс, потом добавил, сделал миграцию, а изменений нет, оказалось, что в базе уже был индекс на эту колонку.

Comment: @OwDafuq да так и есть. Но это не уникальный индекс. Более того, моя задача немного сложнее. У меня на самом деле есть таблица для связи многие ко многим. То есть там целых 2 свойства навигации. И уникальный индекс мне надо установить на 2 свойства :)

Comment: В таком случае, я так думаю, что никак по другому не сделать. Делайте 2 обычных поля для Id'ов, а потом на них накидывайте индексы. Даже в офиц. документации майкрософт так сделано. В IdentityDbContext так сделано: https://i.ibb.co/yBRWxVN/2023-09-15-104349895.png

Comment: _таблица для связи многие ко многим. ... там целых 2 свойства навигации. И уникальный индекс надо на 2 свойства_ - всё это поместите в вопрос!

Comment: Хотелось бы увидеть код сущностей, о которых идёт речь, код DbContext'а, а также узнать какая СУБД используется.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov поясните пожалуйста. Я, конечно, могу все это вывалить в вопрос, но зачем в данном случае такие подробности? Суть же вопроса именно в том, как можно заставить EF явно создать индекс на свойство навигации (через Fluent API). Если получится это, то получится и на группу полей. Я намеренно максимально абстрагировался от деталей, чтобы не перегружать людей информацией.

Comment: _указывал в качестве индекса его строковое представление_ - да, это один из рабочих вариантов. _завтра конвенция именования может поменяться и все индексы придется переписывать_ - логично: отказались от строгой статической типизации (не создали свойство явно), получили проблемы с поддержкой проекта. / А если так: `.HasIndex(nameof(Person) + "Id")`? Проблема переименований колонки решена. Можно пойти дальше и суффикс индекса брать откуда-то ещё: `.HasIndex(nameof(BotMember) + DbSettings.IndexSuffix)`

Comment: _могу все это вывалить в вопрос, но зачем в данном случае такие подробности?_ - отвечу вашими же словами: (причины объяснять сейчас не буду). КЕК. / Ладно, объясню. 1. Видя больше кода, лично мне проще представить, что нужно в конечном итоге. 2. В разных СУБД есть разные индексы. В некоторых можно задавать такие комбинации, которые невозможны в других. 3. Бывало, я тратил много времени на ответы, на написание кода, который прекрасно работал у меня. Но авторы вопросов упорно твердили, что у них не работает. В итоге оказывалось, что мы используем разные версии библиотек/фреймворков/СУБД/etc.

Comment: Что касается конвенций. [Model bulk configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/bulk-configuration). [Model building conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#model-building-conventions). Появилось в EF 7. Мне неведомо, какая версия у вас.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, ну да, справедливо. Не всегда понятно до каких пор можно обобщать и абстрагироваться )  У меня PostgreSQL, EF Core 7.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, вот эта штука `.HasIndex(nameof(BotMember) + DbSettings.IndexSuffix)` не совсем корректна, этот синтаксис просто создает индекс с именем, но да, там дальше можно прикрутить нужные свойства по строковым именам. Так вот, если изначально конвенция не задавалась, то никто же не будет писать `nameof(Property) + DbSettings.Suffix`. То есть при изменении конвенции все равно придется бегать по индексам и руками все менять. А учитывая что никаких ошибок компиляции не будет, неизвестно, когда всплывет ошибка.

Comment: К тому же, если изначально использовались разработческие миграции, а потом миграциями начнет заниматься отдельный человек. Сразу отвечу на вопрос, "а почему это может произойти". Например, был MVP, выстрелил, начали делать полноценный продукт. Ну и конечно, в полноценном продукте хочется больше контроля над ситуацией и меньше default behavior. То есть поведение по умолчанию тоже должно быть строго регламентировано в коде, а не в кишках сторонней библиотеки

Comment: Есть два пути: возлагаем контроль или на компилятор, или на людей. В первом случае делаем свойство `PersonId`. Во втором случае пишем комментарии в коде и руководство, как, что и где менять вручную, бегая по индексам. Безусловно, комментарии и руководство быстро устареет. / Ещё вариант: написать статический анализатор на Roslyn. Вариант действенный, но нужен в команде человек, способный его написать.